# Can we put <content> inside a <shadow> tag?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there a way to put something like `<content select=".someClass"></content>` inside a `<shadow>` tag in a polymer template like so:

```
<shadow>
    <content select=".someClass"></content>
</shadow>
```

If so how? because when I try it doesn't show at all.

Comment: Can you please add the code you are trying? We need to be able to reproduce the error or at least examine your attempt in order to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no declarative way to do this. It is possible to do it with JavaScript by selecting an element that you know exists in the `<shadow>` and then using `getDistributedNodes()` to pull the content out of your insertion point and append it to that known element.

In Polymer you can do this pretty easily leveraging [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding)

If you know that the parent element has an element in it with an `id` of `foo` you could do something like this:

```
// hacky pseudo code
// assuming you have a <content id="content"> element
var content = this.$.content.getDistributedNodes().array();
content.forEach(function(node) {
  this.$.foo.appendChild(node);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks my problem here is that I'm trying to extend `core-scroll-header-panel` so that it can switch modes like [Polymer Gmail](https://poly-mail.appspot.com/) for example, where when you select a message the whole header switches colours etc... and I wanted to encapsulate the logic in something like, `scroll-altmode-header-panel`. Does this mean I should use composition instead of extension?

ps. you've helped me tremendously with all your tutorials!! Thanks

Comment: Yeah, composing it inside of an element that handles swapping the content may be easier than inheriting. Often times I don't try to inherit from things that have UI because it can be hard to mess with the internals.